# Como acessar um iframe usando Selenium Python

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver

Alguém sabe como eu posso acessar um iframe de uma página web sem o ID e o NAME do iframe ?

eu sei que exite um comando chamado`switch_to_frame`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
# Pega o XPath do iframe e atribui a uma variável
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="editor"]/div[3]/div[3]/iframe")

# Muda o foco para o iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# Retorna para a janela principal (fora do iframe)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```